# If any value equals any value condition doesn't accept two words

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, conditional

I am creating a workflow in SharePoint Designer and am using the "If any value equals any value" condition.

I want to check if the current item is in a particular folder. The folder has two words to it's name: let's say the folder is called "This Folder". The if condition looks like this now: If CurrentItem:URL Path contains This Folder.

I set a task in the true part of the condition to email myself, then I have a task at the end of the workflow to email the CurrentItem:URL Path. I only get the second email. And when I look at the URL it has /[site]/[subsite]/This Folder/[filename] yet it did not pick it up in the if condition.

I've tried using quotes like: "This Folder". Still did not work. Also many articles I've read shows the user using the same syntax and apparently returned the right item for them when they were looking for something with two words.

Note: A workaround I found, but don't want to use is using the CurrentItem:Encoded Absolute URL containts This%20Folder. Since the URL is encoded it can't have spaces so using %20 makes it all one word, but I'd prefer to keep all my if checks with CurrentItem:URL Path

Comment: why you dont check with the particular folder ID. if i understood, the folder doesn't change

Comment: @AhmedBouchaala That might work. How do I get the folder ID? I'm in SharePoint Designer and I can get the List ID of the Doc Library the folders are in, but not sure how to find folder ID.

Comment: do you have workflow manager installed ? I mean can you use 2013 workflow ? If yes you can get this using REST API

Comment: @AhmedBouchaala I don't think we do. Strictly 2010 stuff on my machine.